# Web apps for visualization of probability distributions

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, teaching

I am looking for a tool to demonstrate how the shapes of some basic probability distributions (binomial, hypergeometric, Poisson, exponential and normal) change as a function of their parameters.

I have previously used Matlab's disttool, but I find this cumbersome and visually messy. I could of course make an R script, but for pedagogical reasons I would prefer something with sliders – ideally something the students could play with themselves in their browsers.

I found [a Shiny app by Matthew Leonawicz](https://leonawicz.github.io/blog/post/shiny-app-distributions-of-random-variables/) that seemed to be what I'm looking for, but all links to it appear to be dead. The others I have found are all missing the hypergeometric and Poisson distributions.

Comment: David Kahle wrote such an applet: see ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v22n2/kahle.pdf.  It seems to be no longer available; you might want to contact him about any current or newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out (via [this README file](https://github.com/leonawicz/snapapps/blob/master/README.md)) that the mentioned Shiny app by Matthew Leonawicz can be run locally in R with

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("leonawicz/snapapps")
library(snapapps)
snapp("rv4")
```

(The description for accessing it online does not work, however.)

I also liked [this "Distribution calculator"](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/dist_calc/), which is online, although it is missing many probability distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I found these two apps very useful

1. Very comprehensive interactive app by Caltech [Probability Distribution Explorer](https://distribution-explorer.github.io/index.html)
2. Nice R Shiny app by [Probability Distributions](https://statdist.ksmzn.com/)